# Convergence test for 3x-x+13

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm in Calc II and am trying to find what convergence test to use for the following infinite series:

$$\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{3x-x^2+13}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Does this series converge?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1: $\dfrac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt{x^3+1}}\sim \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{x}}, x \to \infty$, where under $f\sim g$ we understand $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

Hint 2 :$\dfrac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} \gt \dfrac{(2x-1)}{\sqrt{2x^3}}$

Comment: hmm, still pretty puzzled . . . is the ~ "approximately equal to?" Where does the 2x^3 come from?

Comment: 1. $\sim$ usually is called equivalence 2. as $x^3+1 \lt 2x^3$, then $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^3+1}} \gt \frac{1}{\sqrt{2x^3}}$